# Compile library project with module es6 but still support projects with module none

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

I have a project that uses typescript with the module option set to none.

I use namespaces and all the bundling is done using .NET MVC bundles.

This project uses several libraries that I developed the same way.

Now, I want to upgrade those libraries to use es6 modules without loosing the support for my "no modules" project.

I have update my tsconfig.json and now it looks like the snippet below:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "declaration": true
    },
    "include": [
        "app/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

I have updated the code to use `export/import`.

And I'm able to generate the library with the same structure using gulp for moving the assets.

But once I copy the library new code to the project I get errors since the generated d.ts contain `export` statements.

How can I set the TS compiler to generate the d.ts in a friendly "no module" way?